# How to use clang::TypeVisitor::Visit to descend down the type structure

Tags: c++, templates, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I understood Visitor Pattern in C++ and curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) individually.
But I am having a trouble trying to understand how to use *clang::TypeVisitor::Visit* method to recursively descend down a type structure.
For example, I have a C++ function object like below and I want to get the type of template parameter (enumT) and eventually get its declaration ( where that enum is declared)

```
enum unscoped_enum {
     val_3,
     val_4
};
template <unscoped_enum enumT>
class funcObject{
 public:
 void operator()() const {}
};
```

My derived visitor class looks like:

```
class DerivedVisitor : public TypeVisitor<DerivedVisitor> {

void *Visit(QualType T) {
      if (T.isNull())
        return nullptr;
   return Visit(T.getTypePtr()) //not sure this is correct
  }
}
```

My question is : how do I figure out which Visit* methods to implement inorder for me to get the EnumDecl?
Like `VisitEnumType(const EnumType et)` is one of them.
But what are the rest?
Also, if I start Visit with a QualType, is calling Visit with `QualType.getTYpePtr`, the right way?

Comment: I've been thinking about your question, but it's not clear what you want. clang's `TypeVisitor` seems to be part of their AST. I.e. it's designed for that application. I don't think you can just drop it in another context. Whats the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: For an AST dump like this : https://godbolt.org/ I am trying to get the declaration of the template parameter val_3, and perform some checking on the enum declaration. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you building a compiler? Or what 's your application?